# recovering a (permanently) deleted Outlook task

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, data-recovery, microsoft-outlook-2007

Last night I accidentally deleted an Outlook 2007 task that was in my deleted folder. this task contains important data that I would like to recover. I tried using Pandora recovery freeware to no avail. Does anyone know a way to recover this lost Outlook task?

I am running Win XP operating system